# How to send a direct message to all members of a server?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to implement a function that will be sending PM to every member of channel.
How to do that? I have that fragment responsible for sending PM to user, but how to get every user from channel?

Comment: This could get your bot ratelimited if you have a lot of members in the channel.

Comment: It will be always about 20-25 people.

Comment: That will definitely get ratelimited. Maybe you want to add a new channel with only the members of the channel, and send the message there

Comment: @MrMythical how is that different from sending a message directly to the original channel?

Comment: Good point, there is no difference. It will be kind of hard for them to pull this off without getting ratelimited

Answer (score 1):

Theres a built-in function called [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in Javascript . With this you can send a DM to all members in your server with DMs open

Here is an example

```js
client.on("message", message => {
        if (message.content === "!dmall")
            message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
                member.send(`Hello`).catch(e => console.error(`Couldn't DM member ${member.user.tag}`))
            })
```

Comment: You should include a code example. Also, if this wasn’t from another site, remove the quote formatting.

Comment: Done @MrMythical .